# Scrape a webpage and put into a table form using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to test scraping card grades and putting into columns of each grade from this page:
https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1986/fleer/36766

The only way I can pick anything up is with this code but I've tried html_table() as well and it doesn't pick anything up.

```
read_html("https://www.psacard.com/pop/basketball-cards/1986/fleer/36766") %>% 
  html_text2() %>% 
  .[1]
```

I'm hoping to have a data frame with columns for each grade 1-10 for each player as a row.

Comment: Have you tried using RSelenium? It looks like the website might be loading the tables with jQuery/javascript so {rvest} can't pick it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://www.psacard.com/Pop/GetSetItems" %>%
  request() %>%
  req_headers(Accept = "application/json") %>%
  req_body_form(
    draw = 1,
    start = 0,
    length = 300,
    headingID = 36766,
    categoryID = 20019,
    isPSADNA = "false"
  ) %>%
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  pluck("data") %>% 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 133 × 39
   SpecID SubjectN…¹ SortO…² Variety CardN…³ CardN…⁴ GradeN0 Grade1Q Grade1 Grade…⁵ Grade…⁶ Grade2Q Grade2 Grade…⁷ Grade3Q Grade3 Grade…⁸ Grade4Q Grade4 Grade…⁹ Grade5Q Grade5
    <int> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>
 1      0 TOTAL POP…       0 NA      NA           NA     653       8    262       3     116       3    440      36       2    952      59       6   2809     114      10   6273
 2 299514 Kareem Ab…    1146 ""      1             1       5       0      1       0       0       0      3       1       0     22       1       0     80       0       0    209
 3 299516 Alvan Ada…    2570 ""      2             2       0       0      0       0       0       0      0       0       0      4       0       0     13       0       0     27
 4 299517 Mark Agui…    5348 ""      3             3       0       0      0       0       0       0      1       0       0      2       0       0     11       0       0     30
 5 299518 Danny Ain…    6400 ""      4             4       0       0      0       0       0       0      2       0       0      3       0       0     10       0       0     24
 6 299519 John Bagl…    8378 ""      5             5       0       0      0       0       0       0      0       0       0      0       0       0      4       1       0     17
 7 299520 Thurl Bai…   10567 ""      6             6       0       0      0       0       0       0      0       0       0      0       0       0      7       0       0     22
 8 299521 Charles B…   10922 ""      7             7       5       0      6       0       3       0     26       2       0     39       2       0    129       4       0    264
 9 299524 Benoit Be…   12281 ""      8             8       0       0      0       0       0       0      0       0       0      0       0       0      9       0       0     16
10 299525 Larry Bird   14279 ""      9             9       0       0      3       0       2       0      4       1       0     16       0       0     46       0       0    131
# … with 123 more rows, 17 more variables: Grade5_5 <int>, Grade6Q <int>, Grade6 <int>, Grade6_5 <int>, Grade7Q <int>, Grade7 <int>, Grade7_5 <int>, Grade8Q <int>,
#   Grade8 <int>, Grade8_5 <int>, Grade9Q <int>, Grade9 <int>, Grade10 <int>, Total <int>, GradeTotal <int>, HalfGradeTotal <int>, QualifiedGradeTotal <int>, and abbreviated
#   variable names ¹​SubjectName, ²​SortOrder, ³​CardNumber, ⁴​CardNumberSort, ⁵​Grade1_5Q, ⁶​Grade1_5, ⁷​Grade2_5, ⁸​Grade3_5, ⁹​Grade4_5
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: Great solution! But I am curious, why did you set categoryID to 20019? Where does that number come from?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez I inspected the HTTP request that the site made and copied the values. I have no idea what they mean, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh I see. I did the same but my categoryID == 20551. Yet it seems like the server accepts requests with other random numbers too.

Comment: This is amazing. can you explain a little bit about what is going on here? I'm interested in learning! @Chamkrai

Comment: I am not an expert myself, but essentially rvest scrapes html generated content. If the content appears to be loading before it present itself, it is fetched with an API. You will need to inspect the network section in the developer tool (F12) and go through the requests that the site make. :) read up on httr2 and httr package